# How to sum two columns by row using data.table syntax?

Tags: r, sum, data.table

Here is the data.table that I'll be referring to in this question. My goal is to sum the `data1` and `data2` columns, and give the results in a new column called `sum`. Below are some of my recent attempts and the results that I get from them. Obviously, none of the results are correct or they are errors. I know that there are many questions on SO that tackle questions similar to this, but I haven't found the solution to this problem yet. It's probably something simple that I'm just not catching. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? In the future, I would like to add columns that give the sd, mean, median, and sem of these columns. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
> sum_tabnew
      location       bin       time data1 data2 loc_id condition loc_coord
   1:    Loc01 (-0.24,1]   0.966764   258     0      1    WT_CTL        a1
   2:    Loc01     (1,2]   2.000012   399     0      1    WT_CTL        a1
   3:    Loc01     (2,3]   2.999657   502     0      1    WT_CTL        a1
   4:    Loc01     (3,4]   3.999978   284     0      1    WT_CTL        a1
   5:    Loc01     (4,5]   4.999684   335     0      1    WT_CTL        a1
  ---                                                                     
8540:    Loc96 (114,115] 115.000607     0    90     96   MUT_CTL       h12
8541:    Loc96 (115,116] 115.984122     0   708     96   MUT_CTL       h12
8542:    Loc96 (116,117] 116.967636     0   383     96   MUT_CTL       h12
8543:    Loc96 (117,118] 117.967847     0     0     96   MUT_CTL       h12
8544:    Loc96 (118,119] 119.000967     0     0     96   MUT_CTL       h12
```

```
#Get a vector of all the 'data' columns
data_vec <- colnames(sum_tabnew)[grepl("data",colnames(sum_tabnew))]

#Change all the 'data' columns data types to double, so they won't have to be changed later
sum_tabnew[ , (data_vec) := lapply(.SD, as.double), .SDcols = data_vec]
```

```
test_sum <- sum_tabnew[, list(sum = sum(test_tab)), by = list(condition, time)]
> test_sum
      condition       time     sum
   1:    WT_CTL   0.966764 2294112
   2:    WT_CTL   2.000012 2294112
   3:    WT_CTL   2.999657 2294112
   4:    WT_CTL   3.999978 2294112
   5:    WT_CTL   4.999684 2294112
  ---                             
1066:   MUT_CTL 115.000607 2294112
1067:   MUT_CTL 115.984122 2294112
1068:   MUT_CTL 116.967636 2294112
1069:   MUT_CTL 117.967847 2294112
1070:   MUT_CTL 119.000967 2294112

test_sum <- sum_tabnew[, sum(.SD), .SDcols = data_vec, by = list(condition, time)]
> test_sum
      condition       time   V1
   1:    WT_CTL   0.966764 3492
   2:    WT_CTL   2.000012  399
   3:    WT_CTL   2.999657 2194
   4:    WT_CTL   3.999978  284
   5:    WT_CTL   4.999684 2520
  ---                          
1066:   MUT_CTL 115.000607 3181
1067:   MUT_CTL 115.984122 4524
1068:   MUT_CTL 116.967636 6925
1069:   MUT_CTL 117.967847 2060
1070:   MUT_CTL 119.000967 2159

test_sum <- sum_tabnew[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x)), by = list(condition, time)]
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

**UPDATE**
Per request from r2evens, here is the data in a consumable format

```
> dput(head(sum_tabnew,10))
structure(list(location = c("Loc01", "Loc01", "Loc01", "Loc01", 
"Loc01", "Loc01", "Loc01", "Loc01", "Loc01", "Loc01"), bin = structure(1:10, levels = c("(-0.24,1]", 
"(1,2]", "(2,3]", "(3,4]", "(4,5]", "(5,6]", "(6,7]", "(7,8]", 
"(8,9]", "(9,10]"), class = "factor"), time = c(0.966764, 
2.000012, 2.999657, 3.999978, 4.999684, 5.999687, 6.999671, 8, 
9.00001, 9.999827), data1 = c(258, 399, 502, 284, 335, 309, 0, 
82, 1916, 2), data2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), loc_id = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), condition = structure(c(12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), levels = c("MUT1", 
"MUT2", "MUT3", "MUT4", "MUT5", "MUT6", "MUT7", "MUT8", "MUT9", 
"MUT10", "MUT_CTL", "WT_CTL"), class = "factor"), loc_coord = c("a1", 
"a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
```

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using `sub_tabnew[, sum := data1 + data2]`? I think I'm missing something, though. Please share a small portion of the dataset in a consumable format, preferably with `dput(head(tab_subnew,10))`, and please add the values you expect to be assigned to those rows.

Comment: Are you intending a single number for all rows? Perhaps `tab_subnet[, sum := sum(.SD), .SDcols = patterns("^data")]`?

Comment: It's possible that sum_tabnew could have more than two 'data' columns, which is why I created the `data_vec`. Also, I want the row sums to be unique for each row, not the same exact number given for every row.

Comment: the dput is invalid, might be missing brackets, and it also seems not to be used for the rest of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for rowwise sums of an unknown number of columns, then we can use `rowSums` internally here:

```r
sum_tabnew[, sum := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = patterns("^data")][]
#     location       bin     time data1 data2 loc_id condition loc_coord   sum
#       <char>    <fctr>    <num> <num> <num>  <int>    <fctr>    <char> <num>
#  1:    Loc01 (-0.24,1] 0.966764   258     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   258
#  2:    Loc01     (1,2] 2.000012   399     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   399
#  3:    Loc01     (2,3] 2.999657   502     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   502
#  4:    Loc01     (3,4] 3.999978   284     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   284
#  5:    Loc01     (4,5] 4.999684   335     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   335
#  6:    Loc01     (5,6] 5.999687   309     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   309
#  7:    Loc01     (6,7] 6.999671     0     0      1    WT_CTL        a1     0
#  8:    Loc01     (7,8] 8.000000    82     0      1    WT_CTL        a1    82
#  9:    Loc01     (8,9] 9.000010  1916     0      1    WT_CTL        a1  1916
# 10:    Loc01    (9,10] 9.999827     2     0      1    WT_CTL        a1     2
```

Since you mentioned wanting to do this with other functions as well, this can be done as:

```r
funs <- list(sum=sum, sigma=sd, med=function(z) median(z, na.rm=TRUE))
sum_tabnew[, c(names(funs)) := lapply(funs, function(fun) apply(.SD, 1, fun)), .SDcols = patterns("^data")]
sum_tabnew
#     location       bin     time data1 data2 loc_id condition loc_coord   sum       sigma   med
#       <char>    <fctr>    <num> <num> <num>  <int>    <fctr>    <char> <num>       <num> <num>
#  1:    Loc01 (-0.24,1] 0.966764   258     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   258  182.433550 129.0
#  2:    Loc01     (1,2] 2.000012   399     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   399  282.135606 199.5
#  3:    Loc01     (2,3] 2.999657   502     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   502  354.967604 251.0
#  4:    Loc01     (3,4] 3.999978   284     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   284  200.818326 142.0
#  5:    Loc01     (4,5] 4.999684   335     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   335  236.880772 167.5
#  6:    Loc01     (5,6] 5.999687   309     0      1    WT_CTL        a1   309  218.495995 154.5
#  7:    Loc01     (6,7] 6.999671     0     0      1    WT_CTL        a1     0    0.000000   0.0
#  8:    Loc01     (7,8] 8.000000    82     0      1    WT_CTL        a1    82   57.982756  41.0
#  9:    Loc01     (8,9] 9.000010  1916     0      1    WT_CTL        a1  1916 1354.816593 958.0
# 10:    Loc01    (9,10] 9.999827     2     0      1    WT_CTL        a1     2    1.414214   1.0
```

Comment: The last example that you gave gives the results I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just apply rowSums to your columns

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Names=sample(LETTERS, 10),data1=sample(1:100,10),data2=sample(1:100,10), data3=sample(1:100,10))
df
data_vec <- colnames(df)[grepl("data",colnames(df))]
data_vec

df$sum <- rowSums(df[,data_vec])
```

Comment: Given in the context of my code, `sum_tabnew$sum <- rowSums(sum_tabnew[,data_vec])
` gives this error `Error in [.data.table(sum_tabnew, , data_vec) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'data_vec' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..data_vec]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.`

Comment: Welcome to SO, by the way